# How to hide the statusBar when react-native modal shown?

Tags: react-native

[image: Screenshot of status bar]

I want to hide the status bar, when modal window is shown.

My setup is as following, but it won't work as expected:

```
<StatusBar animated={true} hidden={true}  translucent={true}>
```

Answer (score 26):

## Use statusBarTranslucent

If your status bar is `translucent`, you can set `statusBarTranslucent` to the `modal`.

Added since `React Native 0.62`

```
<Modal {...props} statusBarTranslucent>...</Modal>
```

Credit: https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal/issues/50#issuecomment-607535322

Comment: I can still see the status bar and the icons on it .

Comment: Do you use it for modal? It should be 'translucent' not 'hide'

Comment: If you want it completely gone, I think you have to try other answer.

Answer (score 10):

**This is a known issue** and there seems to be no official/React way to fix it yet. You can follow the discussion here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7474

I saw a post in this discussion which proposes a hack to hide it, but I haven't tried it on my project. You can also upvote this trick if it works for you.

```
<View style={styles.outerContainer}
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
    <View style={styles.content}>
  </View>
  <Modal animation={fade} transparent={true}>
          {/*Modal Contents Here*/}
  </Modal>
</View>
```

A more solid fix may be changing the theme of activity in native android code.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.ReactNative.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Credits go to **Traviskn** and **mbashiq** who proposed fixes above. I recommend you to subscribe that [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7474).

Comment: `parent="Theme.ReactNative.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen` worked perfectly and its applicable to all screens in the app.

Comment: problem is that if fullscreen mode is on in MI phone then it gives space from bottom

Comment: Since the problem is with Modal component, I had to try with react-native-modal library and prevent using of the RN Modal Component again. by setting the prop coverScreen as false. You can check that it renders in a View component instead: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal/blob/master/src/modal.tsx#L779
Not sure if that might meet your requirements.

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.ReactNative.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

This part resolved the issue, thanks!

Comment: I'm so grateful to you!!! that theme change worked.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the background of StatusBar to solve this problem easily but may not the best.

```
<Modal transparent>
    {Platform.OS === 'android' ?
         <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"/>
         : null
    }
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'}}>
        // ModalContent here
    </View>
</Modal>
```

Just use the same background and this problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentations, you should be able to hide status bar in both iOS and Android using this

```
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
StatusBar.setHidden(true);
```

Comment: this is right, but incomplete. check my answer below

Comment: **it helps me!!**

Answer (score 0):

I am actually facing the same issue for some time, I tried many solutions but I didn't get rid of this problem. I also tried to use native Android code to hide the StatusBar for a single component it works in other component but when I use it in modal it just not working. So, at last, I got a solution that works for me. I remove the modal view and replace it with react-navigation to navigate to a specific path and handle the back button using BackHandler component.

Comment: can you please share the code to hide the status bar natively?

Answer (score 0):

i achieve this creating a custom status bar component with a modal prop:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native'

const MyStatusBar = (props) => {

    const { backgroundColor } = props
    const { barStyle } = props
    const { translucent } = props
    const { hidden } = props
    const { showHideTransition } = props
    const { modal } = props;

    (modal !== undefined) ? StatusBar.setHidden(true) : StatusBar.setHidden(false)

    return (
        <StatusBar showHideTransition={showHideTransition} hidden={hidden} translucent={translucent} backgroundColor={backgroundColor} barStyle={barStyle} />
    )
}
export default MyStatusBar
```

inside my base component `modal` prop is undefined so custom status bar is shown:

```
<MyStatusBar backgroundColor={theme.colors.primary} barStyle={'light-content'} />
```

and then calling inside the component who call the modal:

```
<MyStatusBar modal={modalVisible ? true : undefined} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of my problem is the same, but it appeared a little different than how it is described above.

**Expected behaviour**: When the `Modal` becomes visible the `StatusBar` should hide.

```js
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

...

<Modal
  visible={showModal}
>
  <StatusBar hidden={showModal} />
...
```

**Actual bahviour**: Sometimes the `StatusBar`dissapears as expected, other times just the `StatusBar` background color goes away and the actual StatusBar remains.

**Workaround**: Due to the flickering behaviour I think the problem is a racing condition of the native Android dialog. Therefore, I built a custom `Modal` component that uses the `StatusBar` [imperative api](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#imperative-api) to make sure the `StatusBar` hide call is made before the Modal appears. So far the Problem has not reappeared.

Here is the custom Modal component:

```js
const Modal = ({ visible, children, ...rest }) => {
  const [modalVisibility, setModalVisibility] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (visible) {
      StatusBar.setHidden(true);
      setModalVisibility(true);
    } else {
      StatusBar.setHidden(false);
      setModalVisibility(false);
    }
  }, [visible]);

  return (
    <RNModal
      visible={modalVisibility}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </RNModal>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this

```
<View style={styles.outerContainer}
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
        <View style={styles.content}>
      </View>
      <Modal animation={fade} transparent={true}>
              {/* Contents Here*/}
      </Modal>
    </View>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor={'transparent'} translucent={true} />
```