# React Native Modal hide the status bar in Android---- Screen move up when modal open

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

I'm new in react native and facing below mentioned issue

I'm using react native country picker and Drop down package which internal using react native modal and when that modal opens screen move little upward and status bar is getting hidden.

Thanks in advance [Status bar now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12gMb.png)

I want status bar should be there when model open [Expected Status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsI6Q.png)

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/66685309/5871092

Comment: I already checked this link and nothing working bro

Comment: I resolved this issue by my own. In android styles.xml  change below code
FROM
<item name = "android:windowFullscreen"> true </item>
TO
<item name = "android:windowFullscreen"> false </item>